# ASP.NET Accessing control with dynamically generated IDs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form which contains a repeater with a HiddenField control within whose IDs are dynamically created.

```
Dim tNewOrder As HiddenField = CType(e.Item.FindControl("tNewOrder"), HiddenField)
tNewOrder.ID = "tNewOrder" & CategoryId
```

When I submit the form i'm looping through the repeater and trying to access each HiddenField value but i get error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
For Each CatItem As RepeaterItem In reCategory.Items

    Dim hCategoryId As HiddenField = CType(CatItem.FindControl("hCategoryId"), HiddenField)
    Dim tNewOrder As HiddenField = CType(CatItem.FindControl("tNewOrder" & hCategoryId.Value), HiddenField)
    Response.Write(tNewOrder.Value)

Next
```

Is there a way to find controls with dynamically generated IDs?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way around the issue so thought i'd post it here.

Instead of dynamically creating the control IDs I set ID to 'tNewOrder' and the ClientIDMode:

change this line:

```
tNewOrder.ID = "tNewOrder" & CategoryId
```

to:

```
tNewOrder.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Predictable
```

I then knew the IDs would be generated as tNewOrder_0, tNewOrder_1, tNewOrder_2 per repeater index.

So I could then access the values by:

```
For Each CatItem As RepeaterItem In reCategory.Items

    Dim tNewOrder As HiddenField = CType(CatItem.FindControl("tNewOrder"), HiddenField)
    Response.Write(tNewOrder.Value)

Next
```